# Adding characters to Array using Switch in C

Tags: c

I need help on how to add characters to array using SWITCH(must be done using switch) and then print that array.
Output in array looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSX2r.jpg

I have created the patterns:Rook

Rook

```
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,0,0,0,0,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,0,0,0,0,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);`

Knight
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,0,0,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,0,0,0,177,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,0,0,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);

Bishop
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,219,219,219,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,219,219,219,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);

King

printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,177,177,0,0,177,177,0,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,0,0,0,0,177,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,177,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,177);
printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
```

Comment: You've got some really cool patterns, but it's not clear what sort of array or switch statement you're looking for. Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you're attempting to do and where you're stuck. Otherwise, it's pretty much guesswork as far as what sort of array/switch will actually help you here.

Comment: @ggorlen Characters, it must be 4 cases in switch, 1 for each patern, for example case'K' which should be king

Comment: How will you distinguish `'K'` between Knight and King? An answer shows the use of `enum` which you can also use for indexing arrays, such as the names of the pieces.

Comment: @WeatherVane It does not have to be exactly K, it can be any other character, you can use A,B,C,D if u want, all i need is to add patterns to array with Switch

Answer (score 2):

Although vague, I'll make some assumptions.

I'll assume by "character" you mean one of the following: Rook, Knight, Bishop

First it's a good idea to enclose these "characters" in an enum such as:

```
enum characters {Rook, Knight, Bishop};
```

Next you create your array (and optionally initialise it) as follows:

```
enum characters my_fancy_array[] = {Rook, Knight, Bishop, Knight, Rook};
```

You may populate the array in other ways by maybe an input from the user. The idea might be to then iterate through the array and print its contents in the format you specify.

Finally your switch would look like this:

```
switch (my_fancy_array[i]) {
    case Rook:
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);~
        ...
        break;

    case Bishop:
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
        ...
        break;

    case Knight:
        printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n",177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177,177);
        ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

where `i` is some index of the array.

A good practice is to encapsulate those printfs in functions.

Comment: Yeah, that works but i cant add them to look in this order like in this picture https://imgur.com/a/5405d3u ,  one line seems to always go away